# normalizing pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this dataframe:

```
    HOUSEID   PERSONID  HHSTATE  TRPMILES
0   20000017    1         IN    22.000000
1   20000017    1         IN    0.222222
2   20000017    1         IN    22.000000
3   20000017    2         IN    22.000000
4   20000017    2         IN    0.222222
5   20000017    2         IN    0.222222
6   20000231    1         TX    3.000000
7   20000231    1         TX    2.000000
8   20000231    1         TX    6.000000
9   20000231    1         TX    5.000000
```

I want to normalize `TRPMILES` based on the max value of `HHSTATE`:

```
        HOUSEID  PERSONID  HHSTATE  TRPMILES
    0   20000017    1         IN    1
    1   20000017    1         IN    0.009999
    2   20000017    1         IN    1
    3   20000017    2         IN    1
    4   20000017    2         IN    0.009999
    5   20000017    2         IN    0.009999
    6   20000231    1         TX    0.500000
    7   20000231    1         TX    0.333333
    8   20000231    1         TX    1
    9   20000231    1         TX    0.833333
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df=df.div(df['TRPMILES'].max(level=[2]),level=2).reset_index()
```

I have a million rows with 50 different values for `HHSTATE`.
can you give any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work for you:

```
df["max_trpmiles"] = df.groupby("HHSTATE")["TRPMILES"].transform("max")
df["TRPMILES"] /= df["max_trpmiles"]
df = df.drop("max_trpmiles", axis=1)
```